# Redirect stdout and stderr and override the noclobber option

Tags: bash, files, io-redirection

my `bash` option `noclobber` is on and I already have a file `file1.txt`.

I want to write to existing file by redirecting  *stdout* and *stderr* to `file1.txt` while overriding the `noclobber` option. Below is my command

```
find /etc -type l &>| file1.txt
```

This is giving me `bash syntax error. Unexpected token '|'`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This won't work that way. You have to go with an extended syntax:

`find /etc -type l >| file1.txt 2>&1`

Answer (score 1):

Or you can just switch to another shell like `zsh` where [`&>|` just works](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Redirection.html):

```
find /etc -type l &>| somefile
```